# Python Google Cloud Storage doesn't list some folders

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I started using Google Cloud Storage python API, and got a weird bug.

Some folders aren't returning with the API calls, its like they don't exist.

I tried the following codes:

• List the files/folders in the parent directory:

```
storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_or_name=bucket, prefix=path)
```

My folder is not listed in the iterator

• Check if it exists:

```
bucket.get_blob(path + "/my_folder").exists()
```

Get `AttributeError` bacause `NoneType doesn't have attribute exists()` (i.e., the blob couldn't be found)

• Try to list files inside of it:

```
storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_or_name=bucket, prefix=path + "/my_folder")
```

And get zero-length iterator

---

The folder's path is copied from the Google Cloud Console, and it definitely exists. So why can't I see it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are the folders empty?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not have folders. The namespace is flat. Some tools **emulate** folders.

Comment: @GavinHaynes The folders aren't empty.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yeah I know that. Folders are basically empty files with forward-slash as at the end of their name.

Comment: Incorrect assumption. Folders are not empty blobs. Folders do not exist. All objects are in the root namespace. You can create an empty blob and pretend it is a directory.

Comment: Thats what I meant, I totally agree with you. Its not really a folder, but an empty file that act like a folder.

Ohhh, I think I understand now… Is it possible that Google Cloud Console shows folders even though there is not an empty blob to represent it?

Comment: The Google Cloud Console uses prefixes and delimiters to limit the display of objects. The SDK APIs also provide those features. In the Python SDK look at **blobs.prefixes** entity to see subfolder names. Example, use the **blobs = list_blobs()** method and then **for prefix in blobs.prefixes:** The prefixes do not exist, they are just names that end in **/** as part of a longer object name.

Comment: Got it, thank you  I am still new to this type of storage

Comment: You are welcome. Just throw away your concepts of a file system and instead think of all object names as just being long strings of characters. Then you can search/list based upon components of that long string of characters. The character set is UTF-8 (Unicode) with a length from 1 to 1024 bytes. There are a few reserved characters and strings.

Comment: I get an empty set when using ```blobs.prefixes```, and there is not any similar auto-completion

Comment: Did you set the **prefix** and **delimiter** parameters?

Comment: yes, and I get warning ```Unresolved attribute reference 'prefixes' for class 'HTTPIterator' ``` (but still get an empty set)

Comment: I provided pseudocode. I would need to see the code and library version that you are using. I think you are using the wrong/deprecated **list_blobs** method. Refer to the documentation for help. Review **list_blobs** on this page: https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html

Comment: It works now, I needed to iterate over the blobs before accessing the ```prefixes```.
I would try to play around with it, thank you very much

Comment: @SagiZiv, kindly post your comment as answer. In this way, the community would find your solution very helpful.

Comment: @RobertG You are correct, I have just posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to John Hanley, I have realized my mistake. I was think about it wrong.

There are no folders in Google Cloud Storage, and the "folders" the code returned me are just empty files (but not every folder has empty file to represent it).

So I wrote this code that returns a generator of the files (and "folders") in the storage:

```
def _iterate_files(storage_client, bucket: Bucket, folder_path: str, iterate_subdirectories: bool = True):
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_or_name=bucket,
                                           prefix=folder_path.rstrip('/') + "/",
                                           delimiter='/')

    # First, yield all the files
    for blob in blobs:
        if not blob.name.endswith('/'):
            yield blob

    # Then, yield the subfolders
    for prefix in blobs.prefixes:
        yield bucket.blob(prefix)
        # And if required, yield back the files and folders in the subfolders.
        if iterate_subdirectories:
            yield from _iterate_files(bucket, prefix, True)
```